# Change chart line color

Tags: primefaces

I have this chart:

[image]

I want to fill the area below the line. Is this possible?

Comment: How did you generate it? What have you already tried?

Comment: take the points from mysql,i don't try, i can't find anything like that

Comment: Just the blue line or all areas? I assume you've seen the showcase for area charts

Comment: all areas below the line

Comment: Below all lines, including the blue one? That the intent of my question. If the answer is yes, read my previous comment, something about a showcase. And do the same if you just have one line and your legend is wrong

Comment: I'm embarrassed , it was exactly what I was looking for , thank you